# Angular 6 modal opening on same page not in popup

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-modal

[image]I am have an angular 6 project that includes a toolbar on the top of the page with a "Sign In" button. When I click on this button, I want a modal dialog to appear.

However, I ran there are two issues illustrated in the screenshot below. The first is when I load the page, both modals (outlined in red) are loaded. They should only appear if the appropriate button is clicked.

Stackblitz project is at below link: 
https://stackblitz.com/github/eugene01a/online-exam/tree/master/frontend

The second issue is why are they not appearing in their own dialog popup?

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ModalService
} from "./_services";

import './_content/app.less';
import './_content/modal.less';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  authenticated = false;

  constructor(private modalService: ModalService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  openModal(id: string) {
    this.modalService.open(id);
  }

  closeModal(id: string) {
    this.modalService.close(id);
  }

}
```

```html
<!-- main app container -->
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z10">
  <button mat-button>Online Exams</button>
  <button mat-button>About</button>

  <!-- This fills the remaining space of the current row -->
  <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
  <button mat-button (click)="openModal('signin-modal')" *ngIf="!authenticated">Sign In</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="openModal('signout-modal')" *ngIf="authenticated">Sign Out</button>
</mat-toolbar>

<div class="view-container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<jw-modal id="signin-modal">
  <h1>Sign in button clicked</h1>
  <button (click)="closeModal('signin-modal');">Close</button>
</jw-modal>

<jw-modal id="signout-modal">
  <h1>Sign Out button clicked</h1>
  <button (click)="closeModal('signout-modal');">Close</button>
</jw-modal>
```

Comment: I added a link to the project

Comment: I bet you have an error in your console that's something like 'did you mean to add your compoment to the `entryComponents` list?

Comment: The broken stackblitz link has been fixed